# Get full Device Instance id in Windows Device Driver(WDF)

Tags: registry, wdk, pci, wdf

I'm using WDK 8.1 for customize windows driver.

I want to get **Device instance id** in WDF/KMDF driver,which is unique for each device.

- OS : Windows 7(x64 bit)
- Device Instance id: **{device-ID} \ {instance-specific-ID}**
- There is **registry** entry of Device under: **HKLM/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Enum/PCI/**
- Under HKLM/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Enum//PCI for every device-id ,instance id is there as Subkey.
- Using **WdfDeviceAllocAndQueryProperty** and **WdfMemoryGetBuffer** able to get particular **device id** but now able to get **instance-specific-id**.

Is it possible to get full Device instance id for attached PCI device?

Can anyone suggest possible way so that I can get Device Instance Id using KMDF.

Answer (score 3):

- Yes,it's possible to get full Device instance id (Device id + Instance id).This solutions works and another way may be there.According to my solution check below:
- For example :from `PCI\VEN_1000&DEV_0001&SUBSYS_00000000&REV_02\1&08`

  Device id : `VEN_1000&DEV_0001&SUBSYS_00000000&REV_02` and instance id =  `1&08` (unique id)
- First step is to get Device id as mentioned in question and after that open registry from specific path `HKLM/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Enum/PCI/{device-id}` in this case.Use below functions.
- Use [ZwOpenKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567014(v=vs.85).aspx) and [ZwQueryKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567060(v=vs.85).aspx) and [ZwEnumerateKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566447(v=vs.85).aspx)(for enumeration purpose).This functions can give information about opened registry path.
- For getting subkeys in `ZwQueryKey` function's second argument use   `KEY_BASIC_INFORMATION`as `KEY_INFORMATION_CLASS` .
- After that find subkeys using `ZwEnumerateKey` call for finding subkeys.And after that close handle using [ZwClose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566417(v=vs.85).aspx).
- Take reference check this [CODE](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Content/ViewAssociatedFile.aspx?rzp=%2FKB%2FIP%2Ffirewall_sniffer%2F%2Fsniffer_src.zip&zep=src%2Fdriver%2Fdriver%2Fregistry.c&obid=21001&obtid=2&ovid=1), for finding subkeys enumeration operaion.

Answer (score 2):

Since Device-id and Instance-Id are utterly determined by the PDO driver, we can query the PDO for these information. This is explicitly stated in MSDN([IRP_MN_QUERY_ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ff551679(v=VS.85,d=hv.2).aspx)).

So the code to query Instance-id is like this:

```
void testGetInstanceId(WDFDEVICE wdfdevice)
{
    DEVICE_OBJECT *pdo = WdfDeviceWdmGetPhysicalDevice(wdfdevice);

    KEVENT ke;
    KeInitializeEvent(&ke, NotificationEvent, FALSE);
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb = {};
    PIRP Irp = IoBuildSynchronousFsdRequest(IRP_MJ_PNP, pdo,
        NULL, 0, NULL,
        &ke, &iosb
        );
    Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED; // required initialize
    PIO_STACK_LOCATION stack= IoGetNextIrpStackLocation(Irp);
    stack->MinorFunction = IRP_MN_QUERY_ID;
    stack->Parameters.QueryId.IdType = BusQueryInstanceID;

    NTSTATUS nts = IoCallDriver(pdo, Irp); 

    if(nts==STATUS_PENDING)
    {   // Normally, we will not meet this, bcz QueryId should not be a "slow" operation.
        KeWaitForSingleObject(&ke, Executive, KernelMode, FALSE, NULL);
    }

    if(NT_SUCCESS(nts))
    {
        WCHAR *pInstanceId = (WCHAR*)iosb.Information;
        DbgPrint("InstanceId = %ws\n", pInstanceId); // tested.
        ExFreePool(pInstanceId); // IRP_MN_QUERY_ID require this
    }
}
```

If you'd like to query Device-id, just replace `BusQueryInstanceID` with `BusQueryDeviceID`.

I've verified this myself. It surely works on every version of Windows since Windows 2000.

[2017-06-27] Hmm, I realize a problem regarding two confusing terms: "Device instance id" and "Device instance path" are NOT the same thing. See this post of mine: [How to get Device Instance Path from Windows kernel driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44776328/how-to-get-device-instance-path-from-windows-kernel-driver)

Answer (score 1):

Use WdfDeviceAllocAndQueryProperty**Ex** with **DEVPKEY_Device_InstanceId**

Comment: But sadly WdfDeviceAllocAndQueryPropertyEx is not provided on KMDF 1.9, so it is not available on Windows XP.

Comment: Finally, I figured out the way to accomplish it on Windows XP, see may answer for this question.