# How to get Device Instance Path from Windows kernel driver?

Tags: windows-kernel

Take a look at this example: a USB device in Windows 7 is reported to have Device instance path(DevinstPath) **USB\VID_1EAB&PID_0501\7&25C389C1&0&1** and I know exactly that it corresponds to the so-called hardware-key(hwkey) in registry.

[image]

[image]

Now my question is: When my KMDF driver code has WDFDEVICE handle for that USB device, how can I know its DevinstPath?

I know I can

- send a *BusQueryDeviceID* to achieve the so-called device-id **USB\VID_1EAB&PID_0501**;
- send a *BusQueryInstanceID* to achieve the so-called instance-id **1** .

But I don't know how to get the so-called "instance-path". Could some kernel guru kindly tell me how I can get that?

MSDN doc seems really vague on this!

BTW: I also realize that user-layer function *SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId* actually returns the DevinstPath -- although it is named "InstanceId".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Device instance path can be queried using **DEVPKEY_Device_InstanceId**, using either `WdfDeviceAllocAndQueryPropertyEx` or `IoGetDevicePropertyData` (passing the WDM physical device object)

Comment: Thank you very much. Verified on Win81, `IoGetDevicePropertyData` with `PropertyKey=&DEVPKEY_Device_InstanceId` really does the work. It's a pity that this needs Vista+.

Comment: `WdfDeviceAllocAndQueryPropertyEx` requires KMDF 1.13 so it is not a stock option even for Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Device Instance id is autoincrement sequence.
You can find `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum` in registry;
Rules:NextPareneID.XXXXXXXX.N
XXXXXX use UUID Calculation crc32 values(test ok)
N is 1~9 
Device Instance id format is N&PareneID&random's number&index

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqF7F.png)